# Extracting `Seq[(String,String,String)]` from spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DF with rows of `Seq[(String, String, String)]`. I'm trying to do some kind of a `flatMap` with that but anything I do try ends up throwing

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple3

I can take a single row or multiple rows from the DF just fine

```
df.map{ r => r.getSeq[Feature](1)}.first
```

returns

```
Seq[(String, String, String)] = WrappedArray([ancient,jj,o], [olympia_greece,nn,location] .....
```

and the data type of the RDD seems correct.

`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[(String, String, String)]]`

The schema of the df is

```
root
 |-- article_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- content_processed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- lemma: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pos_tag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ne_tag: string (nullable = true)
```

I know this problem is related to spark sql treating the RDD rows as `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` even though they idiotically say that it's a `Seq[(String, String, String)]`. There's a related question (link below) but the answer to that question doesn't work for me. I am also not familiar enough with spark to figure out how to turn it into a working solution.

Are the rows `Row[Seq[(String, String, String)]]` or `Row[(String, String, String)]` or `Seq[Row[(String, String, String)]]` or something even crazier.

I'm trying to do something like

```
df.map{ r => r.getSeq[Feature](1)}.map(_(1)._1)
```

which appears to work but doesn't actually

```
df.map{ r => r.getSeq[Feature](1)}.map(_(1)._1).first
```

throws the above error. So how am I supposed to (for instance) get the first element of the second tuple on each row?

Also **WHY** has spark been designed to do this, it seems idiotic to claim that something is of one type when in fact it isn't and can not be converted to the claimed type.

---

Related question: [GenericRowWithSchema exception in casting ArrayBuffer to HashSet in DataFrame to RDD from Hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727518/genericrowwithschema-exception-in-casting-arraybuffer-to-hashset-in-dataframe-to)

Related bug report: http://search-hadoop.com/m/q3RTt2bvwy19Dxuq1&subj=ClassCastException+when+extracting+and+collecting+DF+array+column+type

Comment: May I ask who down-voted this question and why ?

Comment: the related bug report was the solution for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, it doesn't claim that it is a tuple. It claims it is a `struct` which maps to `Row`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Feature(lemma: String, pos_tag: String, ne_tag: String)
case class Record(id: Long, content_processed: Seq[Feature])

val df = Seq(
  Record(1L, Seq(
    Feature("ancient", "jj", "o"),
    Feature("olympia_greece", "nn", "location")
  ))
).toDF

val content = df.select($"content_processed").rdd.map(_.getSeq[Row](0))
```

You'll find exact mapping rules in the [Spark SQL programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).

Since `Row` is not exactly pretty structure you'll probably want to map it to something useful:

```
content.map(_.map {
  case Row(lemma: String, pos_tag: String, ne_tag: String) => 
    (lemma, pos_tag, ne_tag)
})
```

or:

```
content.map(_.map ( row => (
  row.getAs[String]("lemma"),
  row.getAs[String]("pos_tag"),
  row.getAs[String]("ne_tag")
)))
```

Finally a slightly more concise approach with `Datasets`:

```
df.as[Record].rdd.map(_.content_processed)
```

or

```
df.select($"content_processed").as[Seq[(String, String, String)]]
```

although this seems to be slightly buggy at this moment.

There is important difference the first approach (`Row.getAs`) and the second one (`Dataset.as`). The former one extract objects as `Any` and applies `asInstanceOf`. The latter one is using encoders to transform between internal types and desired representation.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise that I can ask the content back as basically anything and it'll only be checked at runtime (I'm sure this is mentioned somewhere in the docs). `df.select($"content_processed").map(_.getSeq[(String, String)](0))` also returns _something_, but won't actually run. I'm assuming this is not an artifact of pulling the data in from Cassandra but something inherent to DataFrames?

Comment: Well yes. `Row` is simply a collection of `Any`. All what happens in `getSeq` and other methods is equivalent to `(row(i): Any).asInstanceOf[T]`

Answer (score 0):

```
object ListSerdeTest extends App {

  implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()


  import spark.implicits._
  val myDS = spark.createDataset(
    Seq(
      MyCaseClass(mylist = Array(("asd", "aa"), ("dd", "ee")))
    )
  )

  myDS.toDF().printSchema()

  myDS.toDF().foreach(
    row => {
      row.getSeq[Row](row.fieldIndex("mylist"))
        .foreach {
          case Row(a, b) => println(a, b)
        }
    }
  )
}

case class MyCaseClass (
                 mylist: Seq[(String, String)]
               )
```

Above code is yet another way to deal with nested structure. Spark default Encoder will encode TupleX, making them nested struct, that's why you are seeing this strange behaviour. and like others said in the comment, you can't just do `getAs[T]()` since it's just a cast(`x.asInstanceOf[T]`), therefore will give you runtime exceptions.