# Get elements of type structure of row by name in SPARK SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In a DataFrame object in Apache Spark (I'm using the Scala interface), if I'm iterating over its Row objects, is there any way to extract structure values by name?

I am using the below code to extract by name but I am facing problem on how to read the struct value .

If values had been of type string then we could have done this:

```
 val resultDF=joinedDF.rdd.map{row=> 
      val id=row.getAs[Long]("id")
      val values=row.getAs[String]("slotSize")
      val feilds=row.getAs[String](values)
      (id,values,feilds)
      }.toDF("id","values","feilds")
```

But in my case values has the below schema

```
v1: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- level1: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- level2: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- level3: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- level4: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- level5: string (nullable = true)
```

What shall I replace this line with to make the code work given that value has the above structure.

```
  row.getAs[String](values)
```

Comment: Why are you doing df => rdd => df? Looks like your transformation could be expressed with DataFrame operations and save you a lot of trouble in the process.

Comment: because I have to do some row-wise computations and I require this transformation for traversing dataframes row by row.

Comment: What kind of row-wise computations?

Comment: You can look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502085/transforming-two-dataframes-in-spark-sql/40514493?noredirect=1#comment68285387_40514493

Comment: Doesn't look like you've done much effort between the previous question and this.   The answer for this one lies here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access the `struct` elements my first extracting another `Row` (structs are modeled as another `Row` in spark) from the toplevel `Row` like this:

*Scala Implementation*

```
val level1 = row.getAs[Row]("struct").getAs[String]("level1")
```

*Java Implementation*

```
 String level1 = f.<Row>getAs("struct).getAs("level1").toString();
```