# Get element of Struct Type for a row in scala using any function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing some calculations on row level in Scala/Spark. I have a dataframe created using JSON below-

```
{"available":false,"createTime":"2016-01-08","dataValue":{"names_source":{"first_names":["abc", "def"],"last_names_id":[123,456]},"another_source_array":[{"first":"1.1","last":"ONE"}],"another_source":"TableSources","location":"GMP", "timestamp":"2018-02-11"},"deleteTime":"2016-01-08"}
```

You can create dataframe using this JSON directly. My schema looks like below-

```
root
 |-- available: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- createTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dataValue: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- another_source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- another_source_array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- first: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- last: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- names_source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- first_names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- last_names_id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deleteTime: string (nullable = true)
```

I am reading all columns separately with readSchema and writing with writeSchema. Out of two complex columns, I am able to process one but not other.

Below is a part of my read schema-

```
  .add("names_source", StructType(
      StructField("first_names", ArrayType.apply(StringType)) ::
        StructField("last_names_id", ArrayType.apply(DoubleType)) ::
        Nil
))
.add("another_source_array", ArrayType(StructType(
      StructField("first", StringType) ::
        StructField("last", StringType) ::
        Nil
)))
```

Here is a part of my write schema-

```
.add("names_source", StructType.apply(Seq(
           StructField("first_names", StringType),
            StructField("last_names_id", DoubleType))
  ))
  .add("another_source_array", ArrayType(StructType.apply(Seq(
           StructField("first", StringType),
            StructField("last", StringType))
   )))
```

In processing, I am using a method to index all columns. below is my piece of code for the function-

```
   def myMapRedFunction(df: DataFrame, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {

    val columnIndex = dataIndexingSchema.fieldNames.zipWithIndex.toMap

    val myRDD = df.rdd
      .map(row => {
      Row(
        row.getAs[Boolean](columnIndex("available")),
        parseDate(row.getAs[String](columnIndex("create_time"))),
        ??I Need help here??
        row.getAs[String](columnIndex("another_source")),
        anotherSourceArrayFunction(row.getSeq[Row](columnIndex("another_source_array"))),
        row.getAs[String](columnIndex("location")),
        row.getAs[String](columnIndex("timestamp")),
        parseDate(row.getAs[String](columnIndex("delete_time")))
      )
    }).distinct

    spark.createDataFrame(myRDD, dataWriteSchema)
  }
```

`another_source_array` column is being processed by `anotherSourceArrayFunction` method to make sure we get schema as per the requirements. I need a similar function to get `names_source` column. Below is the function that I am using for `another_source_array` column.

```
    def anotherSourceArrayFunction(data: Seq[Row]): Seq[Row] = {
    if (data == null) {
      data
    } else {
      data.map(r => {
        val first = r.getAs[String]("first").ToUpperCase()
        val last = r.getAs[String]("last")
        new GenericRowWithSchema(Array(first,last), StructType(
          StructField("first", StringType) ::
            StructField("last", StringType) ::
            Nil
        ))
      })
    }
  }
```

Probably in short, I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526054/get-elements-of-type-structure-of-row-by-name-in-spark-scala), where I can get my `names_source` column structure as a struct.

```
names_source:struct<first_names:array<string>,last_names_id:array<bigint>>
another_source_array:array<struct<first:string,last:string>>
```

Above are the column schema required finally. I am able to get `another_source_array`  properly and need help in `names_source`. I think my write schema for this column is correct but I am not sure. But I need finally `names_source:struct<first_names:array<string>,last_names_id:array<bigint>>` as column schema.

Note: I am able to get `another_source_array` column carefully without any problem. I kept here that function to make it better understanding.

Answer (score 8):

From what I see in all the codes you've tried is that **you are trying to flatten the `struct dataValue` column to separate columns**.

If my assumption is correct then you don't have to go through such complexity. You can simply do the follwoing

```
val myRDD = df.rdd
  .map(row => {
    Row(
      row.getAs[Boolean]("available"),
      parseDate(row.getAs[String]("createTime")),
      row.getAs[Row]("dataValue").getAs[Row]("names_source"),
      row.getAs[Row]("dataValue").getAs[String]("another_source"),
      row.getAs[Row]("dataValue").getAs[Seq[Row]]("another_source_array"),
      row.getAs[Row]("dataValue").getAs[String]("location"),
      row.getAs[Row]("dataValue").getAs[String]("timestamp"),
      parseDate(row.getAs[String]("deleteTime"))
    )
  }).distinct

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val dataWriteSchema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("createTime", DateType, true),
  StructField("createTime", StringType, true),
  StructField("names_source", StructType(Seq(StructField("first_names", ArrayType(StringType), true), StructField("last_names_id", ArrayType(LongType), true))), true),
  StructField("another_source", StringType, true),
  StructField("another_source_array", ArrayType(StructType.apply(Seq(StructField("first", StringType),StructField("last", StringType)))), true),
  StructField("location", StringType, true),
  StructField("timestamp", StringType, true),
  StructField("deleteTime", DateType, true)
))

spark.createDataFrame(myRDD, dataWriteSchema).show(false)
```

## using * to flatten the struct column

You can simply use `.*` on *struct column* *for the elements of struct column to be on separate columns*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(col("available"), col("createTime"), col("dataValue.*"), col("deleteTime")).show(false)
```

You will *have to change the string dates column to dateType in this method*

In both the cases you shall get output as

```
+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
|available|createTime|names_source                                   |another_source|another_source_array|location|timestamp |deleteTime|
+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
|false    |2016-01-08|[WrappedArray(abc, def),WrappedArray(123, 456)]|TableSources  |[[1.1,ONE]]         |GMP     |2018-02-11|2016-01-08|
+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: thanks for explanations, tried to reproduce your solution, but only 2nd method works for me. I got some Spark Exception for the first. Anyway, 2nd method is quite useful for me, thanks again)