# How to convert arrays to map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe like this:
[image]

The schema is:
[image]
I want to have the final result like this:
[image]
Namely, to create a map between `_1: integer` and `_2: map` in `site_group`.

How to do this in scala spark?

Comment: Can you add text instead of images so that it would be easy for users to copy and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution. First lets create some sample data similar to yours, btw it would be much more helpful to post a question with reproducible input and output data as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

```scala
val df = Seq(
(999, "2019-05-23", Seq((0,Map(2154 -> 0.545)))),
(511, "2019-06-30", Seq((1,Map(564654 -> 0.255699)))),
(322, "2019-02-10", Seq((2,Map(122 -> 0.896)))))
.toDF("user_id","dt", "site_group_collect")

// +-------+----------+---------------------------+
// |user_id|dt        |site_group_collect         |
// +-------+----------+---------------------------+
// |999    |2019-05-23|[[0, [2154 -> 0.545]]]     |
// |511    |2019-06-30|[[1, [564654 -> 0.255699]]]|
// |322    |2019-02-10|[[2, [122 -> 0.896]]]      |
// +-------+----------+---------------------------+
```

Then we iterate through each item and transform the values of `site_group_collect` using the `map` function of the dataframe:

```scala
df.map{case Row(uid: Int, dt: String, group: Seq[Row]) => 
     val transformed = group.map{ r => Map(r.getInt(0) -> r.get(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Int, Double]]) }
     (uid, dt, transformed)
}
.toDF("user_id","dt", "site_group_collect")
.show(false)

// +-------+----------+-----------------------------+
// |user_id|dt        |site_group_collect           |
// +-------+----------+-----------------------------+
// |999    |2019-05-23|[[0 -> [2154 -> 0.545]]]     |
// |511    |2019-06-30|[[1 -> [564654 -> 0.255699]]]|
// |322    |2019-02-10|[[2 -> [122 -> 0.896]]]      |
// +-------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

The key point here is the representation of the array of tuples `[[0, [2154 -> 0.545]]]` as an array of `Row`s. Another approach would be to represent the tuple as a `case class` i.e:

```
case class Item(pk: Int, m: Map[Int, Double])
```

The line:

```scala
val transformed = group.map{ r => Map(r.getInt(0) -> r.get(1).asInstanceOf[Map[Int, Double]]) }
```

Will extract the `key/value` combination from the existing tuple and assign it to the new created `Map`.

Some related posts:

- [GenericRowWithSchema exception in casting ArrayBuffer to HashSet in DataFrame to RDD from Hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727518/genericrowwithschema-exception-in-casting-arraybuffer-to-hashset-in-dataframe-to/32728585)
- [Extracting `Seq[(String,String,String)]` from spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553059/extracting-seqstring-string-string-from-spark-dataframe)
- [How to add a new Struct column to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615657/how-to-add-a-new-struct-column-to-a-dataframe)